# У меня проблема зажигании светодиода в микроконтроллере устройстве discovery stm32f373

Tags: c++, c, микроконтроллеры, stm32

Использовал STM32 cube mx и библиотеку HAL программа выполнилась, но светодиод не зажегся. Выполнял работу по инструкции [STM Урок 4. Библиотека HAL. STM32 CUBE MX. Светодиоды и кнопка](http://narodstream.ru/stm-urok-4-biblioteka-hal-stm32-cube-mx-svetodiody-i-knopka/)

1. установил ножки для выходов
   [image: stm32]
2. Включаем шину rcc->HSE
3. в Clock Configuration, включил HSE. Настроил по манипулировал следующим образом
   [image: Clock Configuration]
4. Запустил Generate code и перешел в IAR
5. Добавил бесконечный цикл изменив его.

```
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_8);
    HAL_Delay(500);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_8);
}
```

Программа выполнилась без ошибок, но светодиод не мигает. Я изменил ножку выхода на PD8.

Вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я все делал?
2. Объясните причина по которой светодиод может не гореть.
3. Ножки(пины) у микроконтроллера имеют свой идентификатор. Где я могу найти информацию по ножкам? Подойдет ли это [Описание устройства Discovery](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f373r8.pdf)??.
4. Я пользовался английской документацией которую предлагал автор урока, только версию для своего контроллера.[Description of STM32F3 HAL and low-layer drivers](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/a6/79/73/ae/6e/1c/44/14/DM00122016.pdf/files/DM00122016.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00122016.pdf) [STM32F373xx](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f373r8.pdf) Если Русская документация по этому поводу?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте сразу несколько разных вопросов.

Comment: Простите, это один вопрос. все касается мигания светодиода.

Comment: "Где я могу найти информацию по ножкам? и Если Русская документация или учебник по этому поводу?" - это явно не про мигание, и второе, кстати, оффтопик для данного ресурса ;-)

Comment: Не зная функций ножек невозможно включить светодиод. Это нужная информация.

Comment: Не поймите неправильно, я вам пытаюсь помочь, сделать вопрос более четким, убрать лишнее.

Comment: Какая у вас плата STM32? У меня nucleo без дела валяется, возможно вечером попробую.

Comment: Я внесу изменения в вопрос маленькие ```.Description of STM32F0 HAL and low-layer drivers STM32F373xx ``` другую документацию библиотеки указал.

Comment: Так скорее всего ножка не в GPIO режиме. Мультеплексирование смотрите.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на ваш цикл. Вы переключаете состояние пина, ждете 500 мс, а затем переключаете его снова. При следующем проходе цикла, который происходит без задержек, вы опять меняете состояние пина. Соответственно мигания не будет, ваш пин меняет состояние мгновенно дважды. Уберите один из Toggle.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя на скриншоте микроконтроллера сконфигурированы PC7 и PC6, а дергаешь ты PD8.
Назначь в конфигурации микроконтроллера PD8 как выход, и попробуй еще раз.